# Could my processor handle Windows 10 64 bit?

Tags: windows-10, cpu

It's an AMD FX-4300, could it run Windows 10 64 bit? Or, I'd even settle for Windows 7 64 bit. Literally any kind of Windows 7 or up 64 bit.

Comment: It should run Windows 7 smoothly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU will work with 64-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping, but, some articles say I need some CPU instructions that CPU-Z says I don't have? Would it run 64 bit Windows 10, or just 7?

Comment: Can you paste a link to one of those articles? Or at least tell me what CPU instructions you're talking about.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/228042/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-windows-10-to-64-bit-windows-10/ This one in particular. I'm missing the EM64T and VT-x on that list.

Comment: You're misreading that article. For example, it says that VT-x always indicates that NX is available. That doesn't mean NX isn't available just because VT-x isn't.

Comment: Ohh, I figured that the use of "always" was meant to show that it would be unavailable otherwise. Thank you for clearing this up. So, if I were to try to clean install Windows 7 64 bit right now (7 purely because it's what i have on my flash drive, I'm currently running 32 bit Windows 10) I'd definitely be able to?

Comment: See features section....http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-FX-Series%20FX-4300.html

Comment: @AaronWilliamson Well, I don't know your other system specifications, but the CPU won't be a problem.